# Can't understand the meaning of "facile" in these example

Tags: meaning, word-usage, vocabulary, sentence

I found the meaning of facile is easy, getting something without effort.

http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/facile

I have read those sentences. But can't understand it clearly.

I'm trying to understand where is facile used mostly.

What does it mean by

> facile optimism
>       facile response
>       facile manner
>       facile ground
>       facile argument
>
> Facile optimism which we pointed to throughout much of the 1980s is still there.

I took all these from sentence.yourdictionary.com

Can anyone post some sentences using facile?
It would be helpful for me to understand facile better.
Please don't post sentence with same meaning of facile, rather post sentence with different meaning of facile.

Comment: try to google the word.

Comment: Can be voted to close. Folks, do not down vote instead.

Comment: Do you think i didn't google it. I have some problem understanding it in sentences.

Comment: [Definition of facile](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/facile?region=uk&q=facile) All of your examples mean "superficial".

Comment: If you must use Google, use the "define" search: [ define facile ]. Better yet, use a good dictionary. Lots of people here recommend the Oxford online dictionaries and the Macmillan online dictionary. Or go to http://onelook.com/ and look up a word or phrase in many dictionaries at once.

Comment: Incidentally, your sense of site etiquette is good: you did research before posting, and you showed the results of your research. But if your question is about the meaning of a word, it is probably better to show the definitions you found, not just examples, and to explain what was inadequate or confusing about them.

Comment: [Definition of facile again](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/facile?region=uk&q=facile). All of your examples mean "superficial", not "easy". In your other question it did mean "easy".

Comment: @tchrist I wouldn't consider it a duplicate. While `facile` had been explained in that other post, I think guru was still having issues with comprehending this word because there was a lack of explanation regard this word in particular. I'd allow it to stay.

Comment: This is a facile question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facile...

This is a facile response.

This is a superficial response.

If you don't understand what 'facile' is, then look at the synonyms. The biggest one being 'superficial'. If you don't understand what 'superficial' is, then here is a [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superficial).

One that you may take interest in:

> c : presenting only an appearance without substance or significance

As I should know, when I say 'This is a facile response', I was down-voted because it was a 'This is an unsubstantial response'. 'This response holds no significance'.

Therefore (taking out all that I've just given you):

> This is a facile response

Comment: Yes, i think, it can be used in this way.

Comment: @guru if this helped you understand, please mark as best answer so people know that you've found what you were looking for. Glad to help!